# datatables sInfo changing text when table empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Alright, I know I can change the text generally speaking as such:

```
"oLanguage": {
                "sInfo": 'Showing _END_ Sources.',
                "sEmptyTable": "No Sources found currently, please add at least one.",
}
```

the sInfo Property changes the default behavior, and works fine. However when the table is empty sInfo changes to.

> Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries

Which isn't desired, I'd like to have a similar message to my `sEmptyTable` property, but specific for sInfo, of which isn't the one its changing to when it reaches no rows. I have been reading through the API and I can't find any reference thus far for this, and I am wondering if anyone else know the correct way. Cause the only way I can think of is doing it manually and outside of the datatables API and Im pretty sure thats just going to give me some form of other conflict.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

datatables also has oLanguage.sInfoEmpty which will give you what you need.

http://datatables.net/ref

```
"oLanguage": {
    "sInfo": 'Showing _END_ Sources.',
    "sInfoEmpty": 'No entries to show',
    "sEmptyTable": "No Sources found currently, please add at least one.",
}
```

Comment: Thank you - just cured a headache here. =)